# Using user input to create objects in ArrayList with multiple Class associations

Tags: java

I want to create a small Parking System that four classes: one for the user inputs, one with ArrayList (CarPark) maintaining a list of Slots in the Parking, one ParkingSlot Class and one Car Class.

One of the options in the user menu is to park a car in an existing PakingSlot. To do so, the user needs to enter the registration number of the car. As next, the car should be parked in a parking lot and the ArrayList  should be updated.

It is really hard to understand how the classes are supposed to communicate with each other here. It is my understanding that the input of the user has to set the car registration, which needs to then be added to the parking lot, which then has to appear in the ArrayList .
I just don't know how to set up the method which handles the user input here.

The Part of the Application Class that takes the car registration:

```java
else if (choice == 4) {
    System.out.println("Enter the car registration number of the type \"A1234\" ");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    if(input.matches("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")) {
      //not sure that method do I need here to add the car to the Slot in the arrayList
    }
else {
    System.out.println("Invalid Input");
    break;
}
```

**The CarPark Class:**

```java
public class CarPark {
    private ArrayList<ParkingSlot> slots;       

    public CarPark() {
        slots = new ArrayList<ParkingSlot>();
    }
    /**
     * storing Parking Slot 
     */

    public void addParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean newOccupied) {

        ParkingSlot slotObj = new ParkingSlot(newId, newType, newOccupied);
        slots.add(slotObj);
    }

    public void deleteParkingSlot(String identifier) {
        Iterator<ParkingSlot> it = slots.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            ParkingSlot slot = it.next();
            String id = slot.getId();
            if(id.equals(identifier)) {
                if(slot.isOccupied() == true) {
                    System.out.println("Slot cannot be deleted because is occupied");
                }
                else {
                    it.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<ParkingSlot> getParkingSlot() {
        return getParkingSlot();
    }
```

**The ParkingSlot Class:**

```java
public class ParkingSlot {

    private String id;
    private String type;
    private boolean staffMember = false;
    private Car car;

    public ParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean staffMember) {
       this.id = newId;
       this.type = newType;
       this.staffMember = staffMember;
       this.car =null;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setType(String type){
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType(){
        return type;
    }

    public boolean isStaffMember() {
        return staffMember;
    }
    public void setOccupied(boolean staffMember) {
        this.staffMember = staffMember;
    }
    public boolean isOccupied() {
        return car != null;
    }
    public void parkCar(Car car) {
        this.car = car;
    }
    public void removeCar() {
        this.car = null;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return id + "\t" + type + "\t" + staffMember + "\t" + car;
    }
}
```

**The Car Class:**

```
public class Car {

    private String registrationNumber;   
    private String owner;

    public Car(String newregistrationNumber, String newOwner) {
        // Initialize instance variables
        this.registrationNumber = newregistrationNumber;
        this.owner = newOwner;
    }

    public void setRegistrationNumber(String registrationNumber)  {
        this.registrationNumber = registrationNumber;
    }
    public String getRegistrationNumber()  {
        return registrationNumber;
    }
    public void setOwner(String owner)  {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return registrationNumber + owner;
    }
}
```

Comment: `input.matches("[A-Z][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` makes sure your input olny contains alphanumeric characters. Though you should remove redundant [0-9].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After confirming that you registration number is correct you should as for owner of car and create car object which can be stored in a Parking slot object and then into array from CarPark class

This is how you code should look like
[[A-Z][0-9]{4} regex](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5BA-Z%5D%5B0-9%5D%7B4%7D)

```
if(input.matches("[A-Z][0-9]{4}")) { 
   String newRegistration = input;
   System.out.print("Enter the owner's name");
   String newOwner = scanner.nextLine();
   Car car = new Car(newRegistrationNumber, newOwner);

  ArrayList<ParkingSlot> parkingSlot = carPark.getParkingSlot();
  Iterator<ParkingSlot> iterator = parkingSlot.iterator;
  ParkingSlot ps = iterator.next();
  while(iterator.hasNext()) {
     if(!ps.isOccupied()) {
         ps.parkCar(car);
     }
  }
}
```

---

**Tips:**

Add Car as a parameter in ParkingSlot Object

```
 public ParkingSlot(String newId, String newType, boolean staffMember, Car car) {
       this.id = newId;
       this.type = newType;
       this.staffMember = staffMember;
       this.car = car;
 }
```

In function addParkingSlot you could just pass ParkingSlot object

```
public void addParkingSlot(ParkingSlot slotObject) {
        slots.add(slotObj);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Goion,
the thing is I have already created the parking slot and now I need to park the car I'm creating in it. Afterwards the car should also appear in the ArrayList. 

So how do I assign the car to the existing Slot?

Comment: You just loop over array. Find parking spot that is empty (isOccupied) and use  parkingSlot(car) to add car in it. You have created an object of CarPark right?

Comment: @konoshtip I have updated the answer. Let me know if it is not working for you.